# Best practice with big data table using R Shiny

Tags: r, postgresql, amazon-ec2, shiny, bigdata

My client wants to be able to browse through its (big) data displayed in a simple table on a nice Shiny interface.
I created a simple Shiny interface to render a subset of the table.

The issue is that so far I had limited the amount of rows to retrieve to 100000 in my SQL query and when I try to load all the data, my RStudio instance freezes.
The data is a table that has 14 columns and 2,4 Million rows, its size in PostgreSQL is 1GB.

Now, knowing that the Amazon EC2 instance I use is a t2.medium, my questions are:

1) Is the only way to be able to read that amount of data is to move to a bigger EC2 instance ?
2) If this is the only way, is it possible to ramp up the EC2 instance just for the time of loading the big data and then once loaded, come back to a t2.medium ?